# Why do I get an error when I assign a UITextField Delegate to itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am doing the following:

```
 self.firstNameTextField.delegate = self.firstNameTextField;
```

My `firstNameTextField` is a custom text field. I want the custom text field to handle all the delegate events. When I do the above I get the following warning:

> Assigning to id from incompatible type `UITextField`.

What is this warning about and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom `UITextField` class needs to indicate that it conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface MyCustomTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Also make sure that your `firstNameTextField` property is declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic) MyCustomTextField *firstNameTextField;
```

Comment: I just did that and same result.

Comment: @johndoe try a recompile, then.  Xcode doesn't always eliminate some warnings right away.

Comment: recompiled and rebuild and same warning.

Comment: You have to change the property declaration to the type of the custom class as well. UITextField doesn't conform, only your class does.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks That was it! I had to change the property to my custom textfield. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is, the custom class is not conformed with `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

You should add it to your declaration like this

```
@interface MyController : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
```